# How do I sort by values inside a coded value and not treated as a number?

Tags: python, database, spreadsheet

Language is Python.

I have a piece of data that isn't treated as a number but it looks like one. I need to filter out rows in that have a certain integers in certain spots of the code.

It looks like: 123321, 111111, 121111, 321111, etc.

If there is any 3 in the first three places of the code then I need to filter that row out. {333111}
The problem is, I can't filter out codes where there are 3's in the last three spots of the code. {111333}

I know that I could treat it like a value and type in all the specific names for values, but that's incredibly tedious and doesn't help me if I run into this problem on a larger scale.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are propably formated as string, if not you can convert them to string anyway. This allows to slice the string of a number by its digits. The rest is a simply loop.

```
filtered_numbers = list()
numbers = [123321, 111111, 121111, 321111]
for number in numbers:
    if "3" in str(number)[:3]:
        filtered_numbers.append(number)
print(filtered_numbers)
# [123321, 321111]
```